Две идентичные базы. Как выгружать данные?
Существуют две базы, идентичные по структуре. Разные строки подключения и пароли, но на одном сервере. СУБД Firebird.
Необходимо организовать выгрузку общих таблиц с фильтрами по обеим базам. Как поступать?

Вопрос непонятен. Судя по метке .NET необходимо делать это на языке общего назначения c#, f#? Или можно использовать возможности Firebird? Практически в каждой СУБД имеются средства экспорта данных.

Я добавил метки для привлечения внимания к вопросу. Можете удалить те, которые сочтёте нерелевантными.

Выгрузку куда? Напишите больше деталей, сейчас не очень понятно, что нужно.

Выгружаете таблицы из одной базы в одни файлы. Потом таблицы из другой базы в другие файлы. Потом эти файлы объединяете и готово.

В клиентском приложении создаёте два подключения, в каждом отдельно выбираете данные, и, если нужно, дополнительно фильтруете на клиенте.

Нужно больше информации о том, что должно произойти. Я бы сделал по возможности всё на стороне БД, особенно, если структура идентична и фильтры фиксированные и обработки данных особой не нужно. Например, вью по таблицам, из которых надо собрать данные, и потом из него запрос в клиента. Обработка данных движком БД будет эффективнее обработки выгруженных файлов

Выгружаете таблицы из одной базы в одни файлы Как вы себе представляете фильтрацию данным способом?

>Выгрузку куда? Ограничимся SQL и возможностями СУБД. У меня уже есть решение, но я хочу получить ваши варианты т.к. решение медленнее в 4 раза чем если бы делать запрос к одной бд

дополнительно фильтруете на клиенте попробуйте организовать пагинацию с миллион+ фильтрами по двум выгрузкам из разных баз. Легко сказать. На этапе проектирования запросов уже появляются догадки, что так работать не будет
